# проблема с обновлением npm

Tags: node.js

я обновил npm с версии 3.10.10 до 5.4.1 и у меня появилась ошибка

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'..........
```

я ее исправил переустановкой npm и командой

```
npm install -g --save process-nextick-args
```

потом появилась ошибка

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'isarray'.........
```

я ее также исправил опять переустановил npm и перед update до версии 5.4.1 прописал то что было выше и еще

```
npm install -g --save isarray
```

потом снова обновил и теперь у меня появилась ошибка

```
Error: Cannot find module 'core-util-is'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:67:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/npm" --version' }
```

ее исправить как было выше не получается

```
npm install -g --save core-util-is
```

может кто-то что-то подсказать как ее исправить или может я изначально не так что-то делаю?

Comment: снести node и npm, скачать нужную (6 или 8) версию с nodejs.org и поставить нормально.

Comment: я выполняю тестовые задачи в Cloud9IDE и там только апдейт до версии 5,4,1

Comment: ни разу не пользовался этим. У него своё, облачное node-npm или то, что у вас находится? "Там только апдейт" это значит, что нет возможности обновить или оно, если обновить вручную, работать перестанет?

Comment: возможность есть и нужно обновить по заданию там расписано как и даже показано но показано когда были другии версии npm и оно по идеи должно работать без единой ошибки а у меня уже 3-я первые 2 как-то решил гуглом а вот 3-я никак(

Comment: а версия node какая была и какая нужна?

Comment: я все описал в начале

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65415/discussion-between-n3r0bi0m4n-and-xlabuchik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробежался по этим урокам с cloud9. Там просят пользоваться nvm.

Сначала `nvm install v6.11.3`

Затем уже `npm -g i npm`

Comment: еще раз большое спасибо за ответ))

Answer (score 0):

Нагуглил вот такой ответ:

Когда вы сначала выполняете npm install -g npm, оболочка (Bash) будет искать npm в вашем пути, найдите /usr/bin/npm, установленную системным пакетом, а затем используйте его для установки новой версии npm. Новая версия будет установлена ​​в /usr/local/bin/npm.

Теперь ваш путь должен иметь /usr/local/bin/ до /usr/bin/, поэтому вы могли бы подумать, что теперь он подберет обновленную версию в /usr/local/bin/, справа ? Неверно.

После первого раза, когда он ищет их, Bash выполнит исполняемые пути CACHE, поэтому, когда вы скажете npm во второй раз, он все еще использует кешированную версию, которую он сначала нашел как /usr/bin/npm.

Чтобы сообщить Bash, чтобы очистить этот кеш и снова просмотреть путь, вам нужно сделать hash -r.

После установки npm и при этом моя оболочка подхватила новую версию npm